# Better optimization technique using if/else or dictionary

Tags: python, algorithm

Which is better optimization?

- A series of if/else statement which receives the 'string' returns the appropriate function for it. (Around 40-50 if/else statements).
- A dictionary maintaining the key-value pair. key as strings, and values as the function objects, and one main function to search and return the function object.

The main function which actually returns the function object using above method would be called millions or billions of times, so need to do this intelligently. What could be the better way?

For e.g.

```
dict['str1'] = func1
dict['str2'] = func2
and so on..

def main_func(str):
    return dict[str]
```

Or

```
def main_func(str):
    if 'str1':
      return func1
    elif 'str2':
      return func2
```

Which would be better..? if we have 50-60 such strings, and this process needs to be billions of times.

**Storing function object inside dictionary, in function itself:-**

```
def func1():
   if dict.has_key('str1'):
        dict['str1'] = func1
   -- do something --
```

Which is better, this or the above one. This looks much cleaner.? But remember, these functions would be called many times so has_key function would also be called many times.

Thanks

Comment: Write both and **profile them**.

Comment: I go with the dictionary, but rather than checking first if the key is in the dict just have a function to perform what needs to be done if the string is missing and return dict.get(string, string_missing_function)

Comment: Good call! Learn something new every day, I've incorporated your bit into my post. This begins to show that function_lookup doesn't even need defined!

Comment: for smaller lists, if else will be faster, but as size grows dictionary will be. over all dictionary will be better. But I guess a switch-case will be better than them all (which python lacks)!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Choose the dictionary.

The dictionary ...

- is built-in
- is pythonic
- requires less boilerplate code
- has O(1) complexity, compared to the if-else linear O(n) complexity
- isn't guilty of premature pessimization (we have insufficient reason to believe without profiling that it is a less efficient method by a large margin)

I would suggest writing the solution using a dictionary first and seeing if the solution is fast enough for your needs. If so, great, you're done. If not, time it against the other way.

Consider a solution like this (which will return `None` if the string is not found):

```
func_dict = {}
func_dict['str1'] = fun1
func_dict['str2'] = fun2
...
def function_lookup(func_string):
    return func_dict.get(func_string)
```

Then, in your main, simply write `function_lookup(whatever_string_variable)` to attempt a lookup for your function. This avoids the dictionary from being rebuilt every time `function_lookup` is called.

Comment: hmm, should i store the function object inside a function itself, or do it inside a main function only, example is written above.

Comment: As long as you don't define the function in a loop, you should be good.

Comment: It would be... the function would be called many times.... so is has_key function would be called,?? Am i right..?

Comment: Take a look at my edits now. Make sure you give your functions good descriptive names so that you don't forget what everything is doing. Also avoid using variable names of built-ins or things that are already defined, like `dict`.

Comment: Thanks bro, one more thing..
How should I choose my strings (str1, str2)... Right now they are random.. Is the mapping str1, str2, str3 or h1, h2, h3 to the original strings yield better results, or any random string would also yield better performance..?

Comment: The key values won't matter, so make them as readable and sensible as you can.

Answer (score 6):

The dictionary will be faster: it is approximately O(1), while the chain of if statements is O(n). To demonstrate, this script (`make_test.py`) will output a python script that runs some peformance tests:

```
ifs = []
dict = []
for i in range(60):
    string = 'str%d' % i
    ifs.append('  %sif str == "%s": return %d' % ('el' if i else '', string, i))
    dict.append('"%s": %d' % (string, i))

print 'dict = {', ','.join(dict), '}'
print 'def with_dict(str):'
print '  return dict[str]'

print 'def with_if(str):'
print '\n'.join(ifs)

print '''
import timeit

def test_dict():
    for i in range(60):
        with_dict("str%d" % i)

def test_if():
    for i in range(60):
        with_if("str%d" %i)

print 'dict:', timeit.timeit(test_dict, number=10000)
print 'if:  ', timeit.timeit(test_if, number=10000)'''
```

Running it like `python make_test.py | python`, gives me:

```
dict: 0.706176042557
if:   1.67383503914
```

That is, the `if` version is more than 2 times slower than the `dict` version.

Comment: Don't guess, measure! +1 for your results. :-)

Comment: Your comparison leaves out the fact that there is time required to build the dictionary, which is not insignificant and in many cases is not cached when used as a replacement for if statements.

Comment: May be it will be useful to someone: use mapping if tested condition is invariant/constant (use string to store code for later eval()/exec()), otherwise use if-else. Use global scope, closure, or keyword argument (fast hack with security vulnerability) to cache mapping.

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries are one of the heavily tuned parts of python. They produce more readable code.
They should perform better than your if loops. 
However, considering the insertion and other overheads I would suggest you to use timeit module and check the performance.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, it depends on the hash collision performance, but I would imagine storing all the data in a hash and retrieving it would be *slightly* faster.

In any case, the difference probably isn't going to be huge either way. Certainly the hashtable solution is cleaner, so I would recommend that.

The best way to know for sure is to write both versions and test them with a lot of data and measure their performance.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary is better. Dictionary should be backed by a tree/hashmap and has better time complexity than if-else statement (which is roughly linear). Even if the actual run time is not better, the code will be cleaner with dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The average time complexity for [dict lookup](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) is O(1). Worst case is O(n). There are optimisations for dictionaries with only str keys (your use case).

Assuming that the ordering of the tests in the if/else ladder can not itself be optimised based on frequency of the input (e.g. 60 possibilities, 2 of which occur 95% of the time), the complexity for a series of if/else statements is O(n).

A dictionary will therefore give better performance as well as better code readability.

Answer (score 0):

Which every solution looks more elegant and is easier to maintain.

It is more important, in most application programming, to optimize Human time and maintainability then it is to optimize computer time.  Computer time is cheap.  Human time is expensive.

Both solutions have their advantages.

The if/elif solution may provide more flexibility if you need to add control flow later, like nested if/else.

If the data is coming directly from a data source like yaml or a database, then clearly the dict solution is more elegant.