# Python Faster 'If' Usage

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have a list:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

There are multiple `if` usages that check a number is in the a list.

```
while True:
    if 3 in a:
        some_work1  #(different)
    
    if 4 in a:
        some_work2  #(different)
    
    if 8 in a:
        some_work3  #(different)
    
    if 11 in a:
        some_work4  #(different)

    if 12 in a:
        some_work5  #(different)
```

Are there any faster (less cpu usage) methods for these multiple `if` usages? (List `a` is always same. Also it does not change over iterations.). There is no dublicated items in the a list. Works do not overlap.

```
Python 3.8.7
```

Comment: Your question can't be meaningfully answered based on the information given. It also seems like a case of premature optimization. Having said that, if all you want from the list is to check membership, turn it into a set.

Comment: I am not telling to use `in` since `in` all of them will be evaluated

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11445226/3091398) might be a good starting point.

Comment: You have marked this question with the `python` tag. Please update your question with valid python code.

Comment: I have updated the first post.

Comment: Does `a` change over iterations? Otherwise you can just check it once and store the check result.

Comment: List lookups are O(n) but set lookups are O(1) so that would improve membership testing performance (if you can afford to lose duplicates). You can also create a dictionary of methods corresponding to your checks instead of having individual `if` checks. But this is pretty broad

Comment: Oh so many questions to ask here..

Comment: with the `while True:` added it makes more sense why you would want to optimize it...

Comment: This is a simplified code. Actual code is more complex and long. You can simply use ```pass``` command instead of ```some_works```. The most important thing is optimising the given code. I have made several optimisations for the ```some_work``` codes. I don't know why the question is down voted.

Comment: Perhaps this code does not look like a familiar pattern so it got a downvote.  What might help this question is information on `a`: Is it a python list?  How often does it change?  Is this part of a framework within which you are handcuffed (and so we can skip suggesting different patterns to you)?  Is it indeed `while True` free spinning code?  Im guessing that this is an embedded system, perhaps sampling a gpio?

Comment: `Works do not overlap`: have you considered multiprocessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) which has constant insert and retrieve times.  In comparison, the `in` operator performs a linear search in your `a` every check.

I'm not exactly sure what your use-case is without seeing your larger code.  I'm assuming your use-case treats `a` as a list of flags.  As such, a set fits the bill.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 10, 11, 12]
a = set(a)  # pass an iterable

# or simply
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 10, 11, 12}

# or built at runtime
a = set()
a.add(1)
a.add(2)

if 3 in a:
    some_work1
```

If you want a more efficient switch statement, you have already found it.  Python uses `if..elif` for this.  This ensures each is evaluated in sequence with short-circuit.  If you could match multiple outcomes, use a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) (e.g. `{3: functor3, 4: functor4, ...}`.  A functor is a callable, ie it has a `__call__()` method defined.  A `lambda` also satisfies this.

A [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) is an unordered collection that does not allow duplicates.  It's like a dictionary but with the values removed, leaving just keys.  As you know, dictionary keys are unique, and likewise members of a set are unique.  Here we just want a set for performance.

Comment: unpacking is unnecessary

Comment: List a does not have dublicated items. I have printed the "a" after using set. The order is also same. I do not know the difference but there is performance improvement (I measured it by using time function).

Comment: @SuperStormer agree, added more sane approaches to obtaining `a`

Answer (score 0):

**option 1**

You could use a dictionary whose keys are the number in `a` and values the corresponding function. Then you loop over them once and store the needed functions in an array (`to_call`). In the while loop you simply iterate over this array and call its members.

```
def some_work1():
   print("work1")

def some_work2():
   print("work2");

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
func = {3:some_work1,4:some_work2}

to_call = []
for k in func:
   if k in a:
      to_call.append(func[k])


while 1:
   for f in to_call:
      f();
```

**Option 2**

Write some kind of code generator that reads `a` and generates a .py file containing the function calls.