# better/efficient way of doing if elif elif in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

i wanna avoid using too many *if elif* but i don't have any idea how to do it efficiently

```
if ID in a:
  something('1','2')
  
elif ID in b:
  if description.startswith('yes:'):
    something('1','5')
  else:
    something('1','2')
    
elif ID in c:
  something('0','2')
  
elif ID in d:
  something('2','2')
  
elif ID == e:
  something('3','2')

...
```

and around 10 more elifs below it

1. using too many *elifs* also slow down the execution
2. i dont really mind readability since its just my project
3. im just wondering many ways to do if elif elif :) because i think im overusing it most of time

Comment: There's not really enough information here to help. I suspect (and I'm only guessing) that it's the `in` checks that are taking the time. However, it's hard to say, because we don't know what those collections are (i.e. what kind and how many elements they contain). Can you give a minimal, complete example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better optimization technique using if/else or dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445226/better-optimization-technique-using-if-else-or-dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

Theres no real switch case in Python, but since Python 3.10 you can use `match` which is very similar:

```
match subject:
    case <pattern_1>:
        <action_1>
    case <pattern_2>:
        <action_2>
    case <pattern_3>:
        <action_3>
    case _:
        <action_wildcard>
```

You can find out more about it here: https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching